# How to configure mail2tor with thunderbird

Tags: configuration, email

I've been tying to set up my mail2tor email with thunderbird, but not having any luck.

I've followed a couple of guides online which provide server settings etc, but it still doesn't work.

Most recently this one http://free.arinco.org/mail/mail2tor/index3.html
(you have to translate it).

Currently I'm getting a message saying 'connection to server (my username) timed out'

Could anyone provide me with any further settings or info I need to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: It may be down, this seems quite common. See https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10124/mail2tor-onion-dont-work for example

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was trying to set it up with Thunderbird so I could use PGP encryption when sending emails. Could you advise on any other way to send encrypted emails via tor email addresses....or any other tor email services that may work with Thunderbird?

Comment: Not really, I don't use or like gpg or email if I can avoid it. You should maybe look at EnigMail and TorBirdy for Thunderbird.